# Retrieve IP address from Tomcat session ID?

Tags: tomcat, ip-address, sessionid

Based on how is generated the session ID by Tomcat, is there a way to retrieve the IP address of the client from her session ID, using some decoding tool/method?

Using Tomcat 6.

NB: not sure it is relevant / possible at all.

The question could be about *"How is generated the Tomcat session ID, does the calculation use the client IP, and is there a way to get it back"*

**edit**

In case it matters, this is for a one time use, the analysis of an old log file via a Tomcat 6 generated session id. We are not looking at an implementation that works over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it isn't specified how Tomcat or any other container generates a sessionID the answer is 'no'.

Comment: Isn't Tomcat open source? I don't have time now to check the source code, but it should be possible to see what's going on exactly...

Comment: Yes it is open source. So what? It's still unspecified, so they can change it any time, so you can't rely on it. FYI the sessionId is computed from the MAC of a random number, so it isn't reversible, and didn't contain the IP address in the first place.

Comment: And even if you COULD get the IP it would be meaningless because of the use of NAT.  Many users could be behind NAT firewalls, so all users behind a given firewall would show up with the same IP.

Comment: @JG For that purpose it was a security issue, and even having a rough idea of from where the connection was issued would have been a valuable information.